# How can I make successive movements with the same div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

hello I have the following problem, I want to make a series of random movements with the divs and using translate I managed to do only one because when I want to move that element again it returns to its initial position, my question is how can I maintain the position to be able to continue moving it and exchanging positions with other divs?

CSS:

```
body{
  padding: 5rem ;
 }
.elem{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#elem-1{
   background-color: aqua;
}
#elem-2{
  background-color: red;
}
#elem-3{
  background-color: green;
}
#elem-4{
  background-color: blue;
}
#elem-5{
  background-color: violet;
}
#elem-6{
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
#elem-7{
  background-color: gray;
}
#elem-0{
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
.contenedor{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  /* display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr); */

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.move-right{
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: moving-x-right;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.move-left{
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: moving-x-left;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.move-down{
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: moving-y-down;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.move-up{
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: moving-y-up;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes moving-x-right {
  from {
    
   
     
  }

  to {
      transform: translateX(100px);

  }
}
@keyframes moving-x-left {
  from {
    
   
     
  }

  to {
      transform: translateX(-100px);

  }
}
@keyframes moving-y-up {
  from {
    
   
     
  }

  to {
      transform: translateY(-100px);

  }
}
@keyframes moving-y-down {
  from {
    
   
     
  }

  to {
      transform: translateY(100px);

  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="contenedor">
  
  <div class="elem" id="elem-0">1</div>
  <div class="elem" id="elem-1">2</div>
  <div class="elem" id="elem-2">3</div>
  <div class="elem" id="elem-3">4</div>
  <div class="elem" id="elem-4">5</div>
  <div class="elem" id="elem-5">6</div>
  <div class="elem" id="elem-6">7</div>
  <div class="elem" id="elem-7">8</div>


</div>



<script src="/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and JS:

```
window.onload = moveGridElement

function moveGridElement() {
    const elem1 = document.querySelector("#elem-0")
    const elem2 = document.querySelector("#elem-1")
    const elem3 = document.querySelector("#elem-2")
    const elem4 = document.querySelector("#elem-3")
    const elem5 = document.querySelector("#elem-4")
    const elem6 = document.querySelector("#elem-5")
    const elem7 = document.querySelector("#elem-6")
    const elem8 = document.querySelector("#elem-7")
    
    elem1.classList.add("move-right")
    elem2.classList.add("move-left")
    setTimeout(() => {
        elem4.classList.add("move-down")
        elem8.classList.add("move-up")
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        elem1.classList.add("move-down")
        elem6.classList.add("move-up")
    }, 3000);
```

I need that when a div changes places it maintains that position to continue making movements and changing positions with other divs with HTML, CSS and JS only

Comment: Two options. 1> use transition or animation delays. This will let you translate something and move it back again after a delay. This get hairy with the amount of things you're moving. 2> Use something like greensock: https://greensock.com/

Comment: hello and if instead of using translation I use position(lef,top) would it help me in something?? I do not want to use external libraries, it is for my portfolio and I would like to do all the effects

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do. That said, transitions are the best way handle these moves whether you use JS or CSS. Basically you'd be building something that uses animation keyframes. You'd set up the animation for `elem1` to start somewhere, move, pause, and then move again. The reason this is tricky is you have to manually do this for each one and change the timing one by one. Adding another class will just cause a redraw.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a third party library. Using GreenSock is a skill and something to proudly display on your portfolio. It's performant, widely used, and can not only do this easier but also randomly which I think was your goal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, you are very right, knowing how to use more things does not subtract points but rather adds them, I am going to try, learn and implement it